# How to restrict input in angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to restrict the numbers entered in the text box.  The user can enter only enter key after 1 sec.  So, each key entry must have time between 1 sec.

The target is to prevent harsh typing of numbers in the textbox.

Example:
Enter number 1 and then have gap 1 sec and then enter number 2.

In case, if a user enter 1 and then immediately enter number 2, the textbox only will have 1.  2 should be ommited.

I tried settimeout combination to set variable value.
The sample code that i am trying.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApply', []);
var allowKeyPress = true;
app.directive('dateFormat', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        if (value === undefined) return '';
        var inputValue = value.replace(/[^0-9\/]/g, '');
        inputValue = inputValue.replace( /^\\s*/, "" ).replace( /\\s*$/, "" );
        if (inputValue != value) {
          ctrl.$setViewValue(inputValue);
          ctrl.$render();
        }
        return inputValue;
      });

      elem.on("keyup", function(scope) {
////logicssss

      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApply">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <form name="form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
            <fieldset>
              <input type="text" date-format ng-model="date" maxlength="10" class="form-control" />
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting a timeout on the `keypress` event. If a key was pressed in the previous second, prevent the event.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApply', []);
var allowKeyPress = true;
app.directive('dateFormat', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        if (value === undefined) return '';
        var inputValue = value.replace(/[^0-9\/]/g, '');
        inputValue = inputValue.replace( /^\\s*/, "" ).replace( /\\s*$/, "" );
        if (inputValue != value) {
          ctrl.$setViewValue(inputValue);
          ctrl.$render();
        }
        return inputValue;
      });
      var waiting;
      elem.on("keypress", function(e) {
////logicssss
           if (waiting) {
               e.preventDefault();
               return;
           }
           waiting = true;
           setTimeout(function() { waiting = false; }, 1000);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApply">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="style.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <form name="form">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4">
            <fieldset>
              <input type="text" date-format ng-model="date" maxlength="10" class="form-control" />
            </fieldset>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```